# How to use a Personalized Map Style with Here API

Tags: here-api

I would like to customize the map style and found the [Map Style Editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/#15/52.5309/13.3848).

Therefore, I would like to build on the `normal.day.grey` map scheme and just tweak a few styles. The Map Style Editor provides the `normal.day` scheme as yaml.

1. Is there a possibility to access the `normal.day.grey` scheme as yaml so I can load it into the editor and start from there?
2. What would I do with the result? As far as I understand from the [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-info.html) there is a predefined set of schemes and styles which can be combinated together. How would I use my custom style in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please distinguish between *vector* map tiles and *raster*

In the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-info.html) is described about raster Map Tile API - this is prerendered images (with some style) of map. You can't combine them in map view. Except only if some map image tile are partially transparent e.g. '[truck only](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/map-tile/map-tile-truck-transparent)' or '[traffic flow](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-traffic-flowtile.html)'. Then you can add two or more layers on the map.

**Vector tiles** (https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/index.html):

Yes you can customize the vector map style utilize the [Map Style Editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/)

vector style 'normal.day.grey' doesn't exist but you can start with this example on https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/changing_the_map_style - select there 'Reduced day' and download it.

In this example you can find dark style: https://jsfiddle.net/zmeatyxv/1/

Also you can mix a raster tiles and vector tiles adding layers in JS API:

http://jsfiddle.net/uycv9m8x/ - terrain map at the bottom and vector at the top, see code below:

```
/**
 * The function add the "change" event listener to the map's style
 * and modifies colors of the map features within that listener.
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function changeFeatureStyle(map){
  // get the vector provider from the vector layer
  var provider = map.getLayers().get(1).getProvider(); //get provider from vector layer

  // get the style object for the vector layer
  var vStyle = provider.getStyle();

  var changeListener = (evt) => {
    if (vStyle.getState() === H.map.Style.State.READY) {
      vStyle.removeEventListener('change', changeListener);

      // query the sub-section of the style configuration
      // the call removes the subsection from the original configuration
      var vConfig = vStyle.extractConfig([
                            'earth',
                   'landuse.wood',
                   'landuse.forest',
                   'landuse.park',
                   'landuse.builtup',
                   'landuse.national_park',
                   'landuse.nature_reserve',
                   'landuse.green-areas',
                   'landuse.other',
                   'water.small_water',
                   'water.deep_water',
                   'water.river'
                ]);
    }
  };

  vStyle.addEventListener('change', changeListener);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.raster.terrain.xbase/*set terain xbase as base layer*/, {
  center: {lat: 47.60586, lng: 14.27161},
  zoom: 9,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
map.addLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.map);//add vector layer on the top
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
changeFeatureStyle(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/80jtLv16/1/ - raster mobile labels at the bottom and vector tile at the top, see code below:

```
function setStyle(map){
  // get the vector provider from the vector layer
  var provider = map.getLayers().get(1).getProvider(); //get provider from vector layer
  
  // Create the style object from the YAML configuration.
  // First argument is the style path and the second is the base URL to use for
  // resolving relative URLs in the style like textures, fonts.
  // all referenced resources relative to the base path https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/styles/omv.
  var style = new H.map.Style('https://heremaps.github.io/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/change-style-at-load/data/dark.yaml',
    'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/styles/omv/');
  // set the style on the existing layer
  provider.setStyle(style);
}



/**
 * The function add the "change" event listener to the map's style
 * and modifies colors of the map features within that listener.
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function changeFeatureStyle(map){
  // get the vector provider from the vector layer
  var provider = map.getLayers().get(1).getProvider(); //get provider from vector layer

  // get the style object for the vector layer
  var vStyle = provider.getStyle();

  var changeListener = (evt) => {
    if (vStyle.getState() === H.map.Style.State.READY) {
      vStyle.removeEventListener('change', changeListener);

      // query the sub-section of the style configuration
      // the call removes the subsection from the original configuration
      var vConfig = vStyle.extractConfig([
                            'earth',
                  'continent_label',
                  'road_labels',
                  'places',
                  'buildings.address-labels',
                  'roads.shields',
                   //'landuse.wood',
                   //'landuse.forest',
                   //'landuse.park',
                   'landuse.builtup',
                   'landuse.national_park',
                   'landuse.nature_reserve',
                   'landuse.green-areas',
                   'landuse.other',
                   'water.small_water',
                   'water.deep_water',
                   'water.river'
                ]);
    }
  };

  vStyle.addEventListener('change', changeListener);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var mTileServ = platform.getMapTileService({'type': 'base'});
console.log("mTileServ:", mTileServ);
var mobileLayer = mTileServ.createTileLayer('labeltile', 'normal.day.mobile', 512, 'png8', {lg: 'eng', lg2: 'eng'});

//Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mobileLayer/*set mobile layer as base layer*/, {
  center: {lat: 47.60586, lng: 14.27161},
  zoom: 9,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
map.addLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.map);//add vector layer on the top
map.getLayers().add(mobileLayer); //set base layer on top - it depends what you want to achieve
//map.getLayers().add(defaultLayers.vector.normal.map); //here example how to reshuffle the layers

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
setStyle(map);
changeFeatureStyle(map);
```